# want use com.mcxiaoke.volley in android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hello i want create a android apk.

and need to use from "com.mcxiaoke.volley" and "com.android.support:appcompat"

please give me a build app for my app.

current build app is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    //buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "boxweb.asia.shopcenter"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies
{
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

but don't work and show error.

error is : http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/45106145544003944084_Untitled-1.jpg
[image]

i can not download "https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/volley/volley/1.0.0/volley-1.0.0.pom" in android-studio but can download in browser.

help me to install plugin from file.

please help me

Answer (score 1):

Adding volley support can done just by adding `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19` to **gradle.build** dependencies module.

```
dependencies 
{
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

Go through **[Android Volley Library](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)**

Comment: @user5899862 yes yes

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `jcenter()` in your dependencies.  So your build.gradle should have:

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
}


dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

Note:
The `repositories` block can either be in your root `build.gradle` or your `app/build.gradle`.

Comment: This includes the new non-deprecated dependency, the correct way to implement it